# Direct proof for $ \Pi_{i=2}^n (1 - \frac{1}{i^2} ) = \frac{n + 1}{2n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I think that the splitting everything into $$ \Pi_{i=2}^n (1  ) - \Pi_{i=2}^n ({i^{-2}} ) = \frac{n + 1}{2n}$$

may help me, but I don't know any formulas ( or at least don't know how to use ) that will help me. Anyone has tips?

Comment: Have you tried a proof via induction over $n$? And there is something wrong with you formula.

Comment: You can't "*split*" products like that. $(1-a) \cdot (1-b) \ne 1 \cdot 1 - a \cdot b$.

Comment: You cannot split the product in that fashion.

Comment: @JDoe I do have to use direct proof, not induction

Comment: @jelu1999 Telescoping is a disguised form of induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way forward would be through induction as clearly pointed out in the comments by @dxiv

Since this is only one step ahead from @Mostafa Ayaz's answer, look at this only after you've given your best shot:

> simplifying the first continuous product: $$\Pi_{i=2}^n\frac{i-1}{i}=\frac 12 \times \frac 23 \times \frac 34 \times \frac 45 \times \cdots \times \frac{n-1}{n}=\frac 1n$$ 
>  Similarly simplifying the other continuous product: $$\Pi_{i=2}^n\frac{i+1}{i}=\frac 32 \times \frac 43 \times \frac 54 \times \frac 65\times \cdots\times \frac {n+1}{n}=\frac{n+1}{2}$$ 
>  Combining both the products, we have $$\boxed{\Pi_{i=2}^2\left(1-\frac{1}{i^2}\right)=\frac{n+1}{2n}}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$
\prod_{i=2}^n (1-\frac{1}{i^2})
=
\prod_{i=2}^n \frac{(i-1)(i+1)}{i^2}
=
\prod_{i=2}^n \frac{i-1}{i}
\times
\prod_{i=2}^n \frac{i+1}{i}
$$

Comment: Am I going in the right direction? $$  (1 - \prod_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{i} )
\times
( 1 + \prod_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{i} )
$$

Comment: I'm afraid not because $\prod 1+a_n\ne 1+\prod a_n$. From the the products, you can use the telescopic series in a multiplicative way.

Answer (score 1):

1. Reduce to the same denominator each product, giving

$$\Pi_{i=2}^n \frac{(i-1)(i+1)}{i^2} $$

2. Consider the product of the numerators and the product of denominators: every integer will be present twice **but** for the initial and final terms.